# Array change does not rerender template

Tags: vuejs2, vue-composition-api

I have a component in which the template only gets updated when I change a unique value:

```
setup(prop) {
  const uniqueValue = ref(1);
  const fullStar = ref(['fillerValue', false, false, false, false, false]);

  const displayRating = (rating: number) => {
    uniqueValue.value += 1;
    for (let index = 1; index <= rating; index++) {
      fullStar.value[index] = true;
    }
  };

  return {
    uniqueValue,
    fullStar,
  }

<template>
  <div class='ratingContainer'
    v-on:mouseleave='displayRating(storedRating)'>
    <div v-for='n in 5' :key='n'>
      <StarIcon v-if='fullStar[n]' />
      <div style="display: none">{{ uniqueValue }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I have an array called `fullStar`, I want to show a number of stars in the template based on the rating passed to the `displayRating` function.

But the template is only rerendered when I use the `uniqueValue` value in the template even though the `fullStar` array values also change.

Comment: Do I understand correctly you have a template using multiple values but want to re-render only when `uniqueValue` changes ?

Comment: No, it's the other way around :). I've updated the question. So the idea is that when I leave the `ratingContainer` element in the component I call the `displayRating` function and pass the `storedRating` value. This value is available in the component, just omitting it to not clutter the question. The issue is that the template only rerender when I use the `{{ uniqueValue }}`

Comment: Isn't the problem in the `displayRating` function? Current logic completely ignores input parameter and always sets all array items to `false` ....so it may look like component doesn't re-render while it actually does, just with always the same array content...

Comment: Made a mistake in typing the code from head. The idea is that when the function is called it will loop x amount (where x is the rating) and set 1 boolean in the array to true, this works fine locally (when I log it it does show the expected output) but the template is not rerendered. But it seems there's some issues concerning reactivity and arrays in the composition api.  https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api/issues?q=array

Comment: You know you can do this without any array right? Or is this just to experiment with array reactivity specifically?

Comment: How would I do this without an array? I have 5 objects (stars) where I want to set the value to true or false. Easiest would be to use an array and loop through it, at least that's what I think.

Comment: `<StarIcon v-for="n in rating" :key="n" />` where `rating` is value from 1..5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Looks like Vue is having some trouble with reactivity and array values](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api/issues/219). As someone says in that issue:

> Just make in reactive an object whith an array in it. This works very well. Similiar to the data object in vue 2 before:

```
setup() {  
const fullStar = reactive({
  list: [
    { value: false },
    { value: false },
    { value: false },
    { value: false },
    { value: false },
    { value: false },
  ],
});

displayRating = (rating: number) => {
  for (let index = 1; index <= rating; index++) {
     // when this function is called it will set a number of objects in the list array to true and it will update the template.
     fullStar.list[index].value = true
  }
}

return { fullStar };
}

<template>
  <div class='ratingContainer'
    v-on:mouseleave='displayRating(storedRating)'>
    <div v-for='n in 5' :key='n'>
      <StarIcon
        v-if='fullStar.list[n].value' />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Reactivity issues mentioned (currently) exist when using `reactive()`. Everythink is just fine when using `ref([])`. See my [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/array-reactivity-in-vue-3-5zd4p). BTW your `displayRating` functiion is still wrong - if you call it with argument 5 and then 3, array will be all true's anyway...

Comment: I think the point is that you need to wrap your properties (in this case the booleans) in objects. `const fullStar = ref([{ value: false },{ value: false },{ value: false },{ value: false },{ value: false },{ value: false }]);` works, but this does not `const fullStar = ref([false, false, false, false, false, false]);`. The `displayRating` function works, if you call it with 3 it will set the first objects to true and the rest will be false.

Comment: omg just take a look at my demo and stop spreading misinformation all over the place...

Comment: Looks like you're using Vue3 and not the composition api as I tagged. Because even when I copy past your code directly in my app it doesn't update. But your code example works in my project when I wrap the boolean properties in objects as they instruct in the composition api read me. So take a breath and calm down and next time when you build a demo use the correct specs.

Comment: [vue-composition-api] is not tag created for composition-api plugin for Vue 2 as you can see here https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vue-composition-api/info . Using that tag without clearly specifying what version of Vue is used is creating confusion not just for peoply trying to help you, but also for people looking for answers in the future...